# How to make text look *not* clickable

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, design-patterns, accessibility, disable

**Problem:**

I am currently building a textbook exchange website as pictured below. During beta testing users kept trying to click the three snippets of text under the logo ("6 books listed," "12 successful listings," and "2 active users").

*Clarification:* These snippets are simply text; they are not meant to be clicked.

*Clarification 2:* "Successful listings" counts the number of books that sellers/renters have exchanged with buyers. You can interact with open listings (in particular you can edit yours and make offers on others) but the stats are there to demonstrate the effectiveness of the website.

**Question:**

What can I do to make these three pieces of text seem totally unclickable? They're already grayed out as you can see.

[image: Example]

---

### Use in the wild:

Instagram uses a similar list of stats, and these are not clickable.
[image: Instagram]

Comment: Why do you need to make them explicitly non-clickable? ARE the clickable but the users shouldn't click them? Are you seeing people try to click them repeatedly in testing? And if thats the case, why AREN'T they clickable? I would totally expect that clicking on "6 Books listed" would take me to a full list.

Comment: @Mattynabib thank you for your comment. I added clarification to my question; they are not clickable.

Comment: If testing shows uses want to click them then take advantage of that. This is useful information. Make them clickable.

Comment: What @Mayo said. If your user testing is showing you that users want to click the text, don't ignore them!

Comment: what's your intetion in showing these numbers?

Comment: Considering these days clickable text looks exactly the same as non-clickable text... you probably can't.

Comment: This is not the whole solution, hence I'm not adding an answer but a comment. A big part of making sure that stuff looks like content rather than a CTA, is making sure that your CTA look apart from the rest, this way it will be easier for visitors to separate the clickable from the non-clickable.

Comment: Just a note on behavior: The reason why they seem clickable is because it's data related. Now days when something is data related, there is an expectation that it will show users more information on that element. 

I think the more important question is, why are you showing data that doesn't help the user at all?

Comment: Make the text disappear when you mouse over it.  That will stop users from clicking on it!

Comment: @dan1111: better yet: make the text _run away_ from the mouse cursor! Or make the cursor invisible when it gets near! Or, place a nice fat red warning message next to them saying “please do no click here”! Or, just don't display the page at all but only a 404 error!

Comment: It definitely feels very "tab structured" to me, perhaps a reduction in spacing might convey this different?

Comment: Two points on the Instagram justification: **1** Don't assume it works just because they do it. **2** Very few tab navigation solutions use two lines of text.

Comment: what @plainclothes said: the 2 lines of text makes all the difference, so it's not the same as in your case, but a completely different approach.

Comment: While it doesn't fix the issue for touch, be sure that those elements are `cursor: text` and certainly not `cursor: pointer` or even `cursor: default` so that mouse users are less likely to think it's a link.

Comment: I would take it as a hint what users *want* to do, and make it clickable. I *guess* they want to get a rough idea what happens with whatever they enter into the search box, make an informed decision whether they want to get involved.

Comment: Douglas Adams had the answer ([see here](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/44928-arthur-dent-what-happens-if-i-press-this-button-ford)):show a pop-up telling them not to click those bits of text.

Comment: Have you even considered making the clickable and making them do what people expect them to do, which is probably take you to a list of those things? If not you are probably not the right person to be doing UX/UI design.

Comment: I'm shocked no one has pointed this out - those stats ARE clickable on Instagram. When you are logged in, you can click on a user's follower/following count to see who they are following or followed by. (The "posts" count does nothing, because you're already looking at their posts.) I assume this is not allowed while logged out to prevent easy scraping of users' connections.

Comment: As someone who works in mobile advertising I can say that a click is very valuable. Most of my day is spent getting people to click. Every click is a prisoner, don't waste them! If users want to click, let them click and give them something that works for you

Comment: The answer of "just make them clickable!" is fine for this question, but this will come up in search results for other people with maybe not so similar situations. If user testing indicates that people are trying to click something that is completely unnecessary, or the information is already provided, then a different response is needed.

Comment: Make them clickable. Fulfill the expectations of your users instead of finding workarounds.

Comment: Make them black. The color suggests a link.

Comment: Don't display them at all. The fact that there are 6 books listed won't help you when you are starting out (it's too little).

Comment: Suggestion (not germane to the question): change the wording from "6 books listed" to "6 books currently listed" and from "12 successful listings" to "12 books sold". In the former case, I assume that's already what you mean. If not, consider conveying this info, and not the all-time total. (You don't want people judging your success rate as their first action on your site, after all.) In the latter case, the wording is unclear, as evidenced by our confusion on the present ux.SE page.

Answer (score 130):

## tl;dr → use familiar patterns

1. Make the text objects look less like navigational tab controls.
2. The elements seem unnecessarily divided: Place the search field in the main header.
3. Make search look more like search.

[image: Simplified design suggestion]

## Position matters

The subconscious factor making your test subjects want to tap those text objects is positioning. They appear to be tabbed navigation. Look at this example from the Material Design spec that is so popular on mobile and elsewhere.

[image: Material Design tabbed navigation]

## It’s hard to retrain users

Despite your efforts to downplay them, the position appeals to users who want to explore the different views:

> I wonder what books are already listed?
>
> What is a "successful" listing?
>
> Do I know the users that are active here?

Take a minute to think carefully about those questions. I think there are valuable user stories there worth investigating.

## Iterate based on test findings

[image]

Someone, somewhere once said ...

> **You can only make it once, but you can make it better as many times as you need.**

As others have mentioned, users want those things to be navigation. My imagined questions above are hinting at reasons users may want to navigate to the data behind those things.

You don't have to answer every user desire, but when you start to see a pattern you may have stumbled onto something valuable.

Comment: Ah, there's a search box! Having skimmed over the original design, the search box totally did not register as a search box until I saw your mockup that made it obvious that there's supposed to be a search box!

Comment: I love the treatment you made on the text. It definitely makes them feel less clickable. I don't know how but that's just how my brain reacted when I saw it.

Comment: @Andrew I think the bulleted formatting and being in a "sandwiched" position does it. The way they're spaced and positioned at the bottom of the box made them feel like a menu in the original layout.

Comment: @ghoppe I agree I think the bullets do it, text is usually bulleted not links/buttons so I read it as a subheader.

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: In this answer also helps that the amounts of book listed, exchanged and users is bigger. In the question we see 6 books listed and 2 active users. It looks like you can get as list showing just that data. However you quickly know that 11,520 users is just informative.

Comment: @plainclothes Why do you call yourself plainclothes?

Answer (score 124):

Well, since people are trying to interact with this information, I'd use it as an advantage. As mentioned by Mattynabib, it really makes sense.

However, if for some reason you prefer not to, the answer would be to make this snippets of information a homogeneous message. The way it is now, it looks like a mix of a marketing and an interactive element (hence the clicks). So what you need is to keep the marketing side and get rid of this perceived affordance. And in order to do it, simply join the information snippets in a sentence, like

> 6 books listed, 12 successful listings and 2 active users

*Note: I'm not sure if you really want to use this as a marketing copy. If so, I'd look for something better. Also, why "successful listings"? Are there **unsuccessful** ones? If so, why to do an implicit mention to that negative aspect?*

Comment: Good answer, maybe replacing numbers with words will also make it look more like free text.

Comment: Might help the click problem, but kind of a kludge. Presumably the OP probably had a good UX reason to make these numbers easy to spot, scan for, and read, which this solution undermines.

Comment: Yeah, the placement of the elements makes it look like they could be tabs.

Comment: Re: the speculation about "successful listings", my interpretation is that it refers to exchanges that have taken place. I agree that the phrasing isn't ideal; perhaps something like "12 books exchanged" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Mikkel, if that's the case, I agree with you 100%, your proposed phrasing sounds better and has no friction

Comment: @MichaelZuschlag, we don't know the OP intentions, but based in the fact he doesn't care about interaction, only show information for informative purposes, I think this is marketing based. Besides, the "easy to spot on numbers" approach in marketing and advertising isn't the only way, sometimes not even the best way, as [demonstrated by Ogilvy in late 50s](https://johnlyle.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/think_small_vw_beetle_ad_david_ogilvy.jpg)

Comment: @Mikkel, "books exchanged" is far better. Thank you. We have actually changed the phrasing to exactly that in the time since I posted this.

Comment: I agree - listen to Mattynabib's answer below! ;-)

Comment: @Mattynabib, for what it's worth, I have upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 44):

The grey text actually makes them look more clickable as they stand out from the rest of the header.  I would change them to the same color as the rest of the text (black).

Also, instead of "6 books Listed", I would use "Books Listed: 6".  The colon subtly implies, "here's info" rather than "I'm a link".

Comment: Finally, the correct answer. I was scrolling down the page hoping _someone_ would recognize this. When I looked at the OP's screenshot, it was immediately clear to me why the text looked like a link - it wasn't the same color as the header.

Comment: This is also why it _does_ work in the edited-in example: the Instagram stats are shown using the _same_ colour as the main text. The assumption _grey text colour_ -> _greyed out_ -> _non-interactable_ is wrong.

Comment: It's more than just that they stand out more - making text grey on the web frequently indicates specifically that it is clickable, including on some of the most popular sites out there. Look at e.g. the headings on a Google search, or the Facebook 'Like' and 'Share' buttons. The OP's assumption that *grey text* -> *non-clickable* isn't just wrong, it's precisely the opposite of what modern websites have trained users to think.

Comment: Really surprised this wasn't more upvoted. It's also the only difference between OP's work and Instagram's example.

Comment: I agree with this. It is the visual distinction (color change) that makes them stand out. I wanted to click on them also just by looking at them.

Comment: @Odexios, can't agree about it being the only difference. Elsewhere on this page, @ plainclothes and others point out that Instagram uses two lines of text. I would also note the placement: Instagram's positioning can't easily be mistaken for tabs nor a link bar.

Comment: @NathanOsman, iOS, Android, Bootstrap, Angular, jQuery and Foundation colors for disabled state is.... gray. So it's a bit of a reach to call this the correct answer. Maybe for you, certainly not for the big majority of frameworks and commonly accepted patterns

Answer (score 33):

**They should be clickable if users can interact with those things.**

If you are displaying something that summarizes content that is relevant to users, it *should* be clickable to reach the underlying content.

Presumably on a textbook exchange website, users should be able to view the books that are listed.  So let them click on "6 books listed" to get to that view.

Are "successful listings" relevant to users of the site?  If so, again, let them click on that to view all the successful listings.

The same goes for "users".  Can users view the list of users?  If so, let them click on it.

**If users can't interact with what you are counting, why show it?**

For example, if "successful listings" are not something users can interact with, then what is the purpose of telling them how many there are?  It doesn't seem like useful information on its own, and it creates the expectation that successful listings are something relevant to users, that they can interact with.

Perhaps you just want to impress users with the amount of usage of your site.  If so, make sure the information looks like a promotion and not meaningful data.  e.g.:

> CHTB: the second largest book exchange on the internet, used by 1234 users to post 5678 books (and counting!).

Comment: Could you elaborate on "If the information is relevant to users, it should be clickable." a bit more? The way I read that line right now is "all content should be clickable", because you don't place content on a website which isn't relevant.

Comment: I see, if there is underlying content, it should definitely be clickable, we're on the same page again ;)!

Comment: Hi dan1111, thanks so much for your answer. I added this clarification in my question, but "successful listings" counts the number of books that sellers/renters have exchanged with buyers. You can interact with open listings (in particular you can edit yours and make offers on others) but the stats are there to demonstrate the effectiveness of the website.

Comment: @JosephSlote On a side note, I would just call that "listings exchanged". "Successful listing" is awkward at best.

Comment: I can't interact with the text in your answer, why is it shown to me? You can't interact with the text in my comment, why is it shown to you?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, that's a fair criticism, what I said was too universal.  I have added some clarification.

Comment: Explain why the website is showing me (counting!) your reputation under your username, then.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi do you mean the reputation that has an obvious link right next to it that leads to a detailed breakdown? :)

Comment: You need 2-3 clicks to get to the "detailed breakdown", and I can't directly interact with the reputation count.

Comment: @JosephSlote, as a prospective user, I might want to know what books have been exchanged, what the popular books are, what price they brought, etc. For example, knowing that there are 5000 copies of The Art of War listed but only 2 have been exchanged, I probably don't want to waste time listing my copy.

Answer (score 11):

It's a matter of relative 'clickiness' as well. Make the unclickable items less clickable by making the rest *more* clickable. The phrase here is: 'affordance'.

- the position of the three not-clickable items is very prominent: in your design, it's in the center of the page and it intregrates with the logo and the pay-off. That gives them a strong click-affordance.
- graying out hasn't helped you. In this design, it's easily understood as simply a stylistic choice to make this text gray.
- Your 'search' input is maybe not clear enough. Try to make this look more like search-input:add a border, a search-glass and a submit button (for example).
- You might also switch the position of the search bar and the 'unclickable statistics' and make the search bar part of the logo --> mimicking the Google default page.

Comment: By that definition, the greyness already makes them seem (even) less clickable IMO, but maybe I'm just a super-intuitive user...

Comment: @underscor_d I agree, it makes them less clickable, but not enough.

Comment: I meant that due to the dim colour, I wouldn't be likely to think they're clickable anyway... _except_ that they list counts of things, which separately would make me more likely to think they _are_ clickable... so it kinda breaks even IMO.

Answer (score 10):

> What can I do to make these three pieces of text seem totally unclickable? They're already grayed out as you can see.

**sigh**

In the olden days there used to be a standard that clickable text (a hyperlink) was underlined. And another one that grayed out text was inactive. How far have those standard been violated? Look no further than Stack Exchange itself:

[image: Clickable links]

Notice the links from my profile page are not underlined, and in gray. But they are clickable. Now that we have trained users to expect anything to be clickable, you can't just "design" that behaviour away.

As many others have said, since you are saying "6 books listed" it is logical to list those 6 books if you click on those words. Don't fight it.

Answer (score 6):

[image]Since the numbers "6 books listed" "12 successful things" .. are more like highlights.

I would try one of these to make it look like highlight or dashboard sort of numbers:

Increase the font - it makes it pretty obvious that its a heading of sorts.
Have a panel for each item, in this case 3 panels. When I say panel it means having a light background and padding to the text.

Some thing like I tried above, but you can always play around with colors and fonts that suits your design.

Comment: If users are clicking on these sections all you've done is give them a bigger target. How does size imply "don't click me"?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd interpret the text in the original example as links, but I would certainly interpret these as buttons. Plus the marketing copy now takes up a lot more space despite providing no value to the user.

Comment: So your suggestion to make them look less clickable is to make them look like buttons?  lolwut

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey My intention here is to make it look like informative blocks.

Comment: Well, with a "flat" design, they look like buttons. Blame Google?

Answer (score 6):

using inset text shadow gives the appearance of something set in stone:
(with and without)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how one of those looks any more or less "clickable" than the other.  I don't think text style is the problem or the solution here.

Comment: @dan1111 I do but it's _very_ slight and I agree that it is not the solution. Still, it is worth a +1 from me.

Comment: I would have tried to hover the top text to see if it gets underlined like a clickable link. I wouldn't have tried for the bottom one. Definitly not all of the solution, but the effect _is_ there

Comment: Can't rely on this. Given that the effect is slight even at this magnification, I'd say at regular size one can't expect it to be seen in poor contrast situations, on low DPI screens, on CRTs, with users who are moving too fast to notice, with users without perfect vision, and/or with browsers that aren't rendering the styles quite as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You want to make the numbers bigger, change the font/color to differentiate them, and put them on top of the information they are describing.  For example, check out the layout of a certain very popular site (look at the bottom right of this image).  This makes the numbers look more like meters/indicators rather than links.

[image: From StackExchange]

Comment: In that blue box in your picture, there are two things that I can definitely interact with, and three things that I'd wave my mouse over just to see if anything happens.  The only thing that's clearly not clickable is the headline text.

Comment: I didn't realize that those stats _aren't_ clickable but I never had the motivation to click them.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically you could make the text look a bit more "graphic" in nature, something more like a sort of a decoration on that panel; otherwise, I think graying it out is about as far as you can go - once they try clicking and it doesn't work, they'll probably stop.

But if you've tested this and people are consistently clicking there, you may want to consider finding out what they expect to happen when they click in those spots, and then **consider MAKING them clickable... you could be missing an opportunity**.

Comment: What do you mean by "hype-decoration"?

Comment: Something more like an advertisement, something graphic and integrated into the panel than a block of live text that might be a link. It's a stretch, but it's the only thing I could think of offhand to make text look LESS clickable.

Comment: I edited to make that clearer. Also there have been some good comments around making it look more like a single-sentence context, which might remove the "clickable discreet chunks of content" patina from it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because:

1. (probably hard to change) The content begs the question "which?" so people follow their urge to find out.
2. (probably easy to change) They are in a body type font that suggests possible link material. Choose a presentational form - maybe sans-serif, maybe with thin caps, maybe with different weights and/or sizes between digits and letters etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Present it as a table

Links are typically shown as buttons or lines of text. Information is typically shown as a table.

Therefore showing the stats in a slightly more tabular format would deter users from trying to click it.

**Example in the wild**

In fact you already can see in your own instagram example how you could implement this in a subltle way.

Instagram has basically presented their statistic in a table with 3 columns and 2 rows.
1 row of key figures (slightly big) and 1 row with descriptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make it look more complex than a single line of text.

Your Twitter example splits each stat into two lines with different font weight. That should be enough to discourage people from thinking they are links:

[image]

You may change font size, style, color, or add subtle graphics (such as a faint rule between the two lines) to further make it seem as something more complex than a single line of text, which is what a link usually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If making them clickable is not an option, you can try some other treatements. Leave them black, so they look like body copy. You can also add dots (·) between them, to make them look like stats.

The most important thing though is to style the number differently. In your instagram example the number is on its own line, you should do this too.

Answer (score -4):

You could precede those texts with an 'info' icon, with Font Awesome http://fontawesome.io/icon/info-circle/ or whatever you like. And make sure that texts' 'cursor' CSS property is not 'pointer'.

Comment: Surely this icon would just make them look *more* clickable, not less?

Comment: I have to agree with @JonW on this one.

Comment: Then, consider this answer above https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/98156/89792. Really what I would suggest too. As to my suggestion: ok, I agree an icon. But why no one notices 'pointer-events: none' in CSS , as a[t least partial] solution?